# Get response from Retrofit with suspend method for generic objects with Kotlin

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I have a generic method `getData` that should get from the server some POJOs of different objects. Before Retrofit 2.6 without coroutines I could create a method like this:

```
@POST("GetData")
    fun getGenericData(@Query("sessionId") sessionId: UUID, @Body request: RemoteRequest): Call<ResponseBody>
```

An it was fine because I could handle the json contained in the body and deserialize it based on the object name declared in a property inside the json, but with Retrofit 2.6 and coroutines that is not possibile because the return type Call or ResponseBody throw an exception. I do not want to use Response because I do not know the type of the object at compile time and I want to deserialize the returned json separately. Any idea ?

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it right now, but it looks like Gson is not able able to deserialize the object